# regex to scan html and return the URL from a meta refresh tag

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, html-parsing

I'm trying to scan html content to find if the source code includes a meta refresh tag in order to get the URL.

Here are some of the cases of meta http-equiv="refresh" tags I've seen

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=https://example.de/">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=https://example.com/test">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content='0;URL=/test' />
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=/test' />
```

Here is he what I have come up with

```
$url = response.body.scan(/(CONTENT="0;URL=)(.*?)(">)/)
```

/(CONTENT="0;URL=)(.*?)(">)/   will work fine for the first instance without the space between ; and URL not for anything else.

Can someone help me with a regex that will work on all 4 scenarios?

Comment: Don't parse HTML with a regex, use Nokogiri instead. This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15120016/477037

Comment: this might also help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this out:

```
 $url = response.body.scan(/(CONTENT|content)=["']0;\s?URL=(.*?)(["']\s*\/?>)/)
```

Comment: Will this be faster compared to Nokogiri?